# models clash with (META) inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models

in a django project i' ve multiple apps, and the common contains the following models:

```
class CLDate(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Switch(CLDate):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sorted = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Currency(Switch):
    pass
```

In another application i import the Switch, and try to add a ForeignKey to a model which inherits also from Switch

```
class Country(Switch):
    ...
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

.

Running makemigration or anything with manage.py i get the following error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
ads.Country.currency: (models.E006) The field 'currency' clashes with the 
field 'currency' from model 'common.switch'.
```

Why do i get this error, and how could i resolve it? I mean, at the database level it should be only a "pointer" to the currency Model / object, and should be irrelevant to its type. Of course if i change the inheritance type of the Currency to something else, it works fine.

Django: 2.2
python: 3.5.3

.

Comment: What's the point of Currency? Is it really just an empty model that subclasses Switch? It seems that either Currency should be a Proxy model, or Switch should also be abstract.

Comment: True, i don' t know why Switch was not also abstract, it should have been. Thanks.

Comment: Daniel Roseman: how do i accept here your solution?